# What is the energy of the vaccuum : is it the average of $<\phi_H>$, or the value of the potential?

Tags: higgs

If we consider Higgs boson theory, the Higgs potential which is introduced is a mexican hat potential.

Before electroweak symmetry breaking, the field is exactly 0, and the potential is non null.
After electroweak symmetry breaking, the field value is v, but the potential is null.

-->
What is the energy of the vaccuum : is it the average of $<\phi_H>$ (so non null), or is it the value of the potential ?

In particular, I don't see why a field only could represent an energy.

Comment: "...why a field only could represent an energy". Does it? Show your work.

Comment: Does the field expectation value have the right dimensions to be an energy density?

Comment: Do you understand what the energy-momentum tensor is for a scalar field?

Comment: thank you for your answers. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer.

Comment: The vacuum expectation value is the expected value of the *field* in the vaccum. For Higgs, it is $<\phi>=v=246 GeV$. I don't see why the expected value of a *field* is an *energy* ?!?

Comment: @G. Smith : do you mean that the field is a energy-momentum tensor, so that it represents an energy ?

Comment: Anway, even if the field expresses some energy, why is the important quantity the field itself, and not the potential due to the field ?

Comment: No, that’s not what I mean. A field *has* an energy density $\langle T^{00}\rangle$ but a field is not itself that energy density. You must have encountered $T^{\mu\nu}$ for a scalar field theory at some point. It depends on the temporal and spatial derivatives of $\phi$ (quadratically) and on $V(\phi)$. The field expectation value $\langle\phi\rangle$ *does not even have the right dimensions* to be an energy density.

Comment: In the case of a scalar field which has the same value throughout space and is not changing in time, only the potential term in $T^{00}$ contributes to the energy density.

Comment: G. Smith : but since $<\phi>$ is $v$, and since $v=246 GeV$ (GeV is an unit of energy), I would think that $v$ is an energy, so that $<\phi> is an energy. Do you agree ? So field expectation value is an energy ?